# Iterate the start of a list without any import in Python

Tags: python, list, iteration

```
    x = []
    for i in l[0::3]:
        x.append(i)
    for j in l[1::3]:
        x.append(j)
    for k in l[2::3]:
        x.append(k)
    print(x)
```

I want to take a random list like

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

that would return

```
[1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 4, 7]
```

but for a list of any number. is there a way to increase the start by 1 ?

Comment: What language? Python?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```
>>> xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> [x for i in range(3) for x in xs[i::3]]
[1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```